# Laravel 5.4 Multi-Auth Admin and User redirect to user login when login as Admin

Tags: laravel, authentication, admin

**When i login into a admin form when the username and password are correct it will direct me into my user login form not on my desire location which is admin/home**

**ADMIN/AUTH/LOGINCONTROLLER**

```
/**
 * Where to redirect users after login.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/admin/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest.admin', ['except' => 'logout']);
}

public function showLoginForm()
{
    return view('admin.auth.login');
}

/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admins');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a middleware that checks if user is Admin and redirects none admins to home then add that middleware to admin routes in kernel.php

Then your standard login controller would work for both scenarios

Your middleware would look something like this.

Use php artisan make:middleware name-here

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
 $user = $request->user();
 if (!$user || !$user->isAdmin()) {
     throw new AuthenticationException;
 }
 return $next($request);
}
```

Then use your standard login controller which redirects to home. If admin/home is requested you will be redirected to login and the when user logs in and is Admin he will be redirected to admin/home.

In your admin controller you can just use

```
public function __construct()
{
     return $this->middleware('auth') ;
}
```

Add to kernel.php for your middleware

```
admin' => [

'web',

\App\Http\Middleware\your middleware ::class,

],
```

Note 
The isAdmin is a function in my user model which determines if user is Admin or not

Comment: can you give me a sample or a hint because i cant do it im stuct with it

Comment: Updated description